# Filtering services using 'zone' tags with Spring Cloud Consul Discovery and FeignClient

Tags: java, spring-boot, consul, service-discovery, spring-cloud-consul

We have a single Consul cluster in AWS serving all operational environments (dev, qa, uat, prod). When a service registers with Consul, the registered name by default uses spring boot application name. As a result, the same service deployed in dev, qa, prod, cannot be differentiated in a single, operational Consul cluster. So we configured SCC `bootstrap.xml` with `instance-zone` as follows:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      discovery:
        instance-zone: dev
        tags: dev
```

Now, when listing catalog services in Consul we see the following; services appear to be tagged correctly, that's good.

```
{
    "consul": [],
    "helloworldservice": [
        "dev",
        "zone=dev"
    ],
    "helloworldservice": [
        "qa",
        "zone=qa"
    ]
}
```

**Problem**

We use Feign client on the client side (duh):

```
@FeignClient(value = "helloworldservice")
public interface MyBigFatHelloWorldServiceProxy{ ... }
```

..but the problem occurs when discovering services; how to ensure services are filtered by `zone` such that a service deployed to `dev` trying to discover `helloworldservice` is guaranteed to find only the `dev` instance of `helloworldservice`?

Tried using `server-list-query-tags` in the client service, not sure if this is correct:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      discovery:
        enabled: true
        register: false
        instance-zone: dev
        default-query-tag: zone
        server-list-query-tags:
          zone: dev
          dev: dev
  application:
    name: clientservice
```

Also noticed FeignClient supports `serviceId`, can I use this to filter tags on discovery?

```
@FeignClient(value = "helloworldservice", serviceId = "dev")
public interface MyBigFatHelloWorldServiceProxy{ ... }
```

Comment: I've had this question for awhile. I don't know the answer to this, but I finally found someone trying to do this: http://www.ru-rocker.com/2018/07/09/how-to-register-spring-cloud-with-consul-service-discovery/. I thought this would be out-of-the-box but that page creates a custom bean to filter in Ribbon. I've not tried it yet.